# Customize Activate and Deactivate buttons in CRM 2016

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an entity with the following combinations of state and status:

**State / Status**

Active / Open
Inactive / Canceled
Inactive / Closed for Processing
Inactive / Processed

Given these sates/status the default tool tips and texts in the confirmation form of the Activate and Deactivate buttons are not adequate.
Is it possible to customize the Activate and Deactivate buttons that control the state and status of a given record?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't change labels or tooltips dynamically. But you can duplicate these buttons, change label and tooltip and add proper display rule to each one. Also ribbonworkbench would be great help with this.

Comment: If I duplicate the buttons can I have the same behavior? For instance, when I'm deactivating using the CRM buttons it will let me chose if I want to deactivate as Canceled, as Closed for Processing or as Processed. Does ribbonworkbench allow to create buttons with this behavior?

Comment: Ribbonworkbench allows you not only create new button but also duplicate existing so yes I think that it will duplicate button with its behavior